# What is a good way to save a 2D map

Tags: c++, file, boost, file-io

I am currently developing a 2D map editor. Each tile has some properties, like position, collision and some more. Of course, i need to save the amount of columns and rows of the map too.

It would be nice if I could save the map and load it again later. I thought of saving the map as a seperate .png file and the constraints in another file (the coordinates of the tiles, width of the tile etc...). For this I tried to use the boost property tree, to save the map into an xml file..but this is really slow and the xml gets several thousand lines of text. Does anyone know a better way how i can approach this? I never did any serious file saving/loading.

Here is some test code i used to **save** a map.xml:

Note: The tilemap is a 2 dimensional vector

> std::vector< std::vector< Tile* > > m_map;

```
    void TileMap::exportAsXML(std::string &filename)
{
       boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
       pt.put("map.filename", filename);
       filename=filename+".xml";

       pt.put("map.size.cols", m_cols);
       pt.put("map.size.rows", m_rows);
       pt.put("map.size.tile_width", m_tile_width);
       pt.put("map.size.tile_height", m_tile_height);

       int i=0;
       BOOST_FOREACH( std::vector<Tile*> row, m_map )
       {
           BOOST_FOREACH( Tile* t, row )
           {
               pt.put("Tiles."+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( i )+".posX", t->getProperty()->getPosX());
               pt.put("Tiles."+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( i )+".posY", t->getProperty()->getPosY());
               pt.put("Tiles."+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( i )+".blocks", t->getProperty()->getBlocks());
               pt.put("Tiles."+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( i )+".width", t->getProperty()->getWidth());
               pt.put("Tiles."+boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( i )+".height", t->getProperty()->getHeight());
               i++;
           }
       }
       boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> settings('\t', 1);

       write_xml(filename, pt, std::locale(), settings);
}
```

Comment: you can try josn format , it's more compact than xml, if not go, binary

Answer (score 2):

If xml is too big then you can try using [json](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) format to save the file. It's more compact than xml and might save you some lines.

If this solution is not good then you have to write your own format , text or binary, the fastest/smallest would be binary formats. If you don't want the save to be readable and you don't need versioning on those files then binary is the best choice. I think you can even find some library for binary xml so you don't have to change alot in your code.

Also another option is to zip the xml file. You can integrate [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) and compress the file, then save it. This will give surprising format because text files with lots of redundancy can be compressed very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). It's a library for serializing data structures to a binary format on disc. It's not human readable, but should be fast and space efficient.